# Transfer tokens to and from smart contract

Tags: erc-20, tokens, erc-20-approve

I would like to have a new ERC20 token and one or two smart contracts to do automatic trade with specific cryptos.

Example: I can buy 1 token from the contract in exchange for 1 USDT.
I can sell a token for a different price then in the first scenario, say 0.99 USDT, so the contract always "profit".
I need to be able to get tokens or USDT out of the contract to any account wallet and I need to be able to add balace of USDT or tokens to the contract from any account wallet I own and decide to use.

Any tips on if andhow this can be achieved and code samples are much appreciated.

Comment: The question is too broad. Try dividing the problem in small ones that are easier to ask about. Start with a simple case.

Answer (score 2):

in order to do this, you need to merge the deposit and claim functionality in one function. Depositing 1 USDT and receiving the token in exchange is what it means. Claim is for the user to transfer that Token to its EOA / Metamask Wallet. I would suggest you not automate this, as if you implement a price oracle for this, which will give you real-time price of the USDT and tokens . It can take some time to reflect the price and token can be exchanged for the wrong price.